# Find Items in List<T> based on id

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What I am trying to do is get a `List<Feature>` into my object which holds a list of Features.

I have the two main classes which hold the information about the items:

```
public class Feature
{
    public int FeaturePackId { get; set; }
    public string FeatureDescription { get; set; }
    public int FeatureId { get; set; }
    public bool AlwaysOn { get; set; }
}

public class FeaturePack
{
    public int FeaturePackId { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}
```

A FeaturePack has an ID and a List of Features in the pack.

Below I am getting a list of Feautres from `GetPSTNFeaturePacksById()` I then iterate over this list and place the items into seperate lists based on their ID. From here I have two lists. The `SelectFeature` list contains a list of features who's `IDs` are greater than 0. How can I add these to my `FeaturePack` object where the `FeaturePackID` inside the `Feature` is equal to the `ID` of the `FeaturePack`

```
Features = CommonMethods.GetPSTNFeaturePacksById();
foreach (var item in Features)
{
    if (item.FeaturePackId == 0)
    {
        DefaultFeatures.Add(new Feature
        {
            FeaturePackId = item.FeaturePackId,
            FeatureDescription = item.FeatureDescription,
            FeatureId = item.FeatureId,
            AlwaysOn = item.AlwaysOn
        });
    }
    else
    {
        SelectFeatures.Add(new Feature
        {
            FeaturePackId = item.FeaturePackId,
            FeatureDescription = item.FeatureDescription,
            FeatureId = item.FeatureId,
            AlwaysOn = item.AlwaysOn
       });
    }
}
```

In short i would want a `List<FeaturePack>` which contains a `List<Feature>`

How can I produce an output similar to this?

```
FeaturePacks:
    FeaturePackId 1
    Features
        FeaturePackId = 1
        FeaturePackDescription = "lorum ipsum"
        FeatureId = 1
        AlwaysOn = True
        /
        FeaturePackId = 1
        FeaturePackDescription = "lorum ipsum"
        FeatureId = 1
        AlwaysOn = True
    FeaturePackId 2
    Features
        FeaturePackId = 2
        FeaturePackDescription = "lorum ipsum"
        FeatureId = 3
        AlwaysOn = True
        /
        FeaturePackId = 2
        FeaturePackDescription = "lorum ipsum"
        FeatureId = 4
        AlwaysOn = True
    ...
```

**EDIT**

New attempt:

```
var distinctGroups = (from z in SelectFeatures
                            orderby z.FeaturePackId
                            select z.FeaturePackId).Distinct();

        foreach (var gp in distinctGroups)
        {
            foreach (var item in SelectFeatures)
            {
                if (item.FeaturePackId == gp)
                {
                    FeaturePack.Add(new FeaturePack
                    {
                        FeaturePackId = gp,
                        Features = item.AsList()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

The output of this is a FeaturePack for each Feature, how can i modify it so related features are in the same pack?

Comment: instead of `Features.Clear();` do `Features = new List<Feature>` I think you're adding the same reference object to each. This is related to your first attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a simple `GroupBy`:

```
Features.GroupBy(f => f.FeaturePackId)
        .Select(g => new FeaturePack{ FeaturePackId = g.Key,
                                      Features = g.ToList() })
        .ToList();
```

---

To break this down piece by piece:

```
Features.GroupBy(f => f.FeaturePackId)
```

Takes a list of `Feature`s and groups them into an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Key, Value>>`, where the `Key` is the result of the function we provide, in this case `f => f.FeaturePackId`, and the `Value` is a list of the objects we're working with (in this case, `Feature`s). After this statement we have all of our `Feature`s with the same `FeaturePackId` in a group together, with several of these groups (one per `FeaturePackId`).

```
    .Select(g => new FeaturePack{ FeaturePackId = g.Key,
                                  Features = g.ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

This select then takes each group of `Feature`s and creates a `FeaturePack` from it. The group's key is the result of the function from above, `f => f.FeaturePackId`, and the group itself is our list of `Feature`s. The result of this `Select` is an `IEnumerable<FeaturePack>` where each `FeaturePack` has it's `Features` list populated. The final call to `ToList()` converts the `IEnumerable<FeaturePack>` into a `List<FeaturePack>`.

Comment: You can do g.ToList() if it is not in sql

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm not too experienced with Linq can you explain what this is doing?

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
from z in SelectFeatures
order z by z.FeaturePackId into g
select new FeaturePack { 
                        FeaturePackId = g.Key, 
                        Features = g}

public class FeaturePack
{
    public int FeaturePackId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm starting learn LINQ, but it may help you, but it's anonymous type:

```
var SelectedFeatures_lookup = SelectedFeatures.ToLookUp(p=>p.FeaturePackId);
var query =     from feature in SelectedFeatures
                group feature by feature.FeaturePackId into g
                select new
                {
                    FeaturePackId = g.Key,
                    Features = g
                };

foreach(var q in query)
{
       Console.WriteLine("FeaturePack = " + q.FeaturePackId);
       Console.WriteLine("Features: ");
       (foreach var qq in q.Features)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("\t " + qq.FeaturePackId);
            Console.WriteLine("\t " + ...);
       }
}
```

Please try and give me answer if will not work

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
var SelectFeatures = Features.Where(item => item.FeaturePackId != 0)
                .GroupBy(item => item.FeaturePackId)
                .Select(grp => new FeaturePack { FeaturePackId = grp.Key, Features = grp.ToList() })
                .ToList();
var DefaultFeatures = Features.Where(item => item.FeaturePackId == 0).ToList();
```